# Unable to do SCP on multiple machines using Perl's Net::SCP::Expect module

Tags: perl, perl-module, scp

I am trying to SCP from one machine to multiple machines. I have an identity file to use for performing passwordless authentication. I came across Net::SCP::Expect module and it does the job well for one machine but when it moves on to copying the component to another machine, it fails.

Here's the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
use File::Copy;
use Getopt::Long;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Net::SCP::Expect;

my ($war_name, $wrapper_name, $host, $user, $war_build_path, $war_full_path, $war_archive_path, $war_archive_host, $HOME, $scpe, @id_file);

usage() if ( @ARGV < 6 or
            !GetOptions(
                    'war_name:s' => \$war_name,
                    'war_path:s' => \$war_build_path,
                    'wrapper_name:s' => \$wrapper_name,
                    'host=s' => \$host,
                    'user=s' => \$user,
            )
        );


if ($war_name && $war_build_path && $host && $user) {
    printf "Initiating subroutine to copy war on remote machine...\n";
    &copy_war;
}


sub copy_war {
    $war_full_path = "/home/tom/slave/workspace/Rel_Build/rec_dist/$war_name";
    $war_archive_path = "/home/tom";
    $war_archive_host = "xx.xxx.xxx.xx";

    if ( -f $war_full_path ) {
        printf "Copying war: $war_name\n";
        printf "Target Machine: $host\n";
        printf "User: $user\n\n";

        $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(
                                    identity_file => "/home/tom/.ssh/id_file",
                                    host => $host,
                                    user => $user,
        );

        $scpe->scp("$war_full_path", "$HOME") or die $scpe->{errstr};

        printf "War copied on deployment machine. Now moving on to next task of archiving the war...\n";

        $scpe = Net::SCP::Expect->new(
                                    identity_file => "/home/tom/.ssh/id_file",
                                    host => $war_archive_host,
                                    user => $user,
        );

        $scpe->scp("$war_full_path", "$war_archive_path") or die $scpe->{errstr};
        printf "War archived on master\n";
    } else {
        printf "War not found\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

Initiating subroutine to copy war on remote machine...
Copying war: remote-web.war
Target Machine: xx.xxx.xxx.xx
User: tom

Use of uninitialized value $HOME in string at /home/tom/deploy.pl line 59.
War copied on deployment machine. Now moving on to next task of archiving the war...
     at /home/tom/perl/5.18.2/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/Expect.pm line 760.

I tried reading Expect.pm file around the error # but couldn't understand. Does it has anything to do with the earlier object not getting freed up? I couldn't find any method on the CPAN page for this module to close the connection.

**Update:**
Thanks for the reply Len but to be honest, I did not really look at it very seriously because the file was getting copied at the desired location i.e., in the home dir of $user. After i changed it to $ENV{'HOME'} or $ENV{HOME}, even the first SCP is not working now. Now i get the following:

```
Initiating subroutine to copy war on remote machine...
Copying war: remote-web.war
Target Machine: xx.xxx.xxx.xx
User: tom

at /home/tom/perl/5.18.2/lib/site_perl/5.18.2/Expect.pm line 760.ar: Permission denied
```

Comment: I realized the mistake i was committing. To simplify the explanation, in the first SCP, i needed to run the SCP as user A while in second SCP, which was on a different server, I needed a different user. However, in my script, I was using the same user A for performing SCP on both the machines and that’s why it wasn’t working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the `$HOME` environment variable, you want to use `$ENV{HOME}` to look up the value from Perl's ENVironment hash.

Comment: Please check my 'Update' section in the original post above.

Answer (score 0):

use [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aParallel);

```
my $pssh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new;
$pssh->add_host($_) for @hosts;
$pssh->push('*', scp_put => $war_full_path, '~/');
$pssh->run;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion salva! By the way, i realized the mistake i was committing while using module 'Net::SCP::Expect'. The issue is resolved. To simplify the explanation, in the first SCP, i needed to run the SCP as user A while in second SCP, which was on a different server, I needed a different user. However, in my script, I was using the same user A for performing SCP on both the machines and that’s why it wasn’t working.

Comment: @Technext: yes, I am.